# Чем опасна функция eval у JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eval

Чем опасна функция eval в JavaScript на клиентской стороне? Кроме того, что сложнее ее отлаживать не вижу недостатков. Насчет других языков тот же Python или PHP то там все понятно.

Comment: Не считая, что потенциально медленнее, позволит выполнить любой код, и если не следить за происхождением передаваемой в eval строки, возможны дыры в безопасности.

Comment: О какой безопасности идет речь? Ведь пользователь и так может выполнять в консольке код. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Код, который там выполняется, выполняется от имени пользователя. Если это зловредный код, он может, например, от имени пользователя написать письмо (если мы находимся в контексте почтового web-клиента).

Comment: @Node_pro к примеру какие-то персональные данные пользователя уйдут на сторону.

Comment: А разве не тот же эффект, можно добиться через консоль браузера?

Comment: @Node_pro можно и через консоль, но это уже явные действия пользователя, вредоносный код сам по себе не откроет консоль и не запустит себя там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **eval** требует компиляции, каждый раз когда вызывается, потому он замедляет работу скрипта
- Вредоносный скрипт может найти ​​путь для передачи аргумента в **eval** и выполнить любой зловредный код БЕЗ ведома пользователя
- **eval** это плохой подход. Это официальный костыль, всегда есть выход безопаснее и удобнее. Как в хорошей литературе пишут обычно "Если вы используете *eval* или *goto* - значит вы что-то делаете не так"
- **eval** наследует контекст в котором он вызван, каждый раз когда вызывается
- **eval** пытается получить доступ ко всем переменным, до которых может дотянуться, со всеми вытекающими

В любом случае, самая большая проблема **eval'а** это потенциальная дырища в безопасности, размером с вселенную. :) За всем не уследить.

Comment: контекст внутри `eval` зависит от способа вызова, он не всегда наследует текущий

Comment: _Если вы используете eval или goto - значит вы что-то делаете не так_ - как-то слишком категорично

Comment: На счет замедления, без тестов тоже нельзя ничего сказать, причем тестов для разных браузеров

Comment: @Grundy А где это написано? Я в спецификациях читал, что eval всегда биндит текущий скоуп, в новом ES в том числе, не важно как он вызван.

Comment: @Grundy Конечно категорично. Есть правила писанные кровью. Если программист не может писать код без функций, которые трудно отлаживать или которые создают 99-ти процентный риск ошибок или дыр безопасности, то с этим программистом что-то не так.

Comment: @Grundy Про замедление спорить не буду. Очень многое зависит от ситуации, платформы и т.д. и т.п. Но, если рассуждать логически, то крайне очевидно утяжеление исполнения кода, если его нужно постоянно компилировать и биндить скоуп. Просто в некоторых ситуациях это будет "экономия на спичках", абсолютно бесполезная.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41608/discussion-between-grundy-and-slydeath).

Comment: 1,3,4. не относится к безопасности. 2. а в консоли не то же самое юзер может сделать? 5. чем это подрывает безопасность?

Comment: @Kromster 2. Что юзер делает сам - сам дурак. Он с таким же успехом может отдать доступ к своему аккаунту через банальный email-фишинг. Вы же, со своей стороны, должны обеспечить максимальную безопасность пользователю и своему сервису. И, если, вы принимаете от пользователя какие-то данные в eval, то злоумышленник может обмануть пользователя, предложив ему вставить зловредный код в консоль.

Comment: @Kromster 5. Если злоумышленник получит доступ к переменным извне внутри eval, к которым он не должен иметь доступ, то это ничем хорошим не сулит. Если программист использует eval, есть большая вероятность, что у него полно говнокода и дыр. Если в своих силах не уверен, лучше никогда не использовать столь опасные функции.

Comment: Дополните этим ответ пожалуйста. Комментарии редко кто читает.

Comment: @Kromster да я там и так уже общий вывод сделал - это дыра в безопасности. Никто не идеален, не ошибается тот, кто ничего не делает. Код могут сломать с такого угла, с которого вы сами бы никогда не догадались. :) На то они и хакеры, их задача сломать, и иногда остаётся только поражаться сколь голь на выдумки хитра. Я достаточно параноидален и всегда проверяю каждый чих, даже к типам привожу, которые я ожидаю. И это, в том числе, помогает держать код в более стабильном состоянии.